# Send data to notepad from dev c++

Tags: c++

Sir, I am creating my university project on bank database system on dev c++(object-oriented paradigm). So, I want to enter the data in c++ and wanted to save the data in the notepad file.
For Example:
Dev c++ :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int a;
    cout<<"Enter a number"<<endl;
    cin>> a;
}
```

:- When the user enters a number in the console of Dev C++, then the output will be saved in notepad. How will it be??

Sorry.... for unclear question...
Yes, Suraj Roa you got my logic. that show the user input number in .txt file

Comment: "How will it be??". It will be needing more editing before anyone understands your problem better and can help you in any way.

Comment: DO you mean save a user entered number to a txt file??

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "save the data in the notepad file".  What notepad file?  Please [edit] your question to describe what you want to happen to the data in more detail - we may then be able to edit it back down to a more compact question, but at the moment we just don't understand.

Comment: What is a "notepad file"`?

Comment: @Ron I'dont think he wants UI automation.

Comment: @MichaelWalz The _notepad_ part was confusing. Unclear whether OP wants to open a notepad and send text to it or simply save to file.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    cout << "Enter number : " << endl;
    cin >> a;

    // open file stream
    ofstream file;

    file.open("number.txt");
    file << a;

    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a stream to external file and then you can use it like std output stream (cout).

All you need to understand this mechanism you can find [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/).